# WORKFORCE SCHEDULING / Days in a row constraint / CP

Tags: optimization, constraints, operations-research

I'd like to ask your opinion about how to model a constraint. The constraint can be either linear or non linear.

CONTEXT: employee scheduling. $N$ employees can be assigned to $M$ shifts, each shift belongs to a day $D$. I created a binary variable $x_{n,m,d}$ where $x_{n,m,d} = 1$ indicates that employee $n$ is assigned to shift $m$ at day $d$ (the $d$ index is useful for other constraints).

CONSTRAINT TO MODEL: each employee prefers to work at least $K$ days in a row. (i.e. $k$ consecutive days with at least one shift per day)

What I already did is to model a variable "working_day [n,d]" that tells if the employee n has at least a shift in the day $d$.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your topic, you already have a binary variable $x_{n,m,t} \in \{0,1\}$ that indicates whether employee $n$ is assigned to shift $m$ at day $t$ and a binary variable $y_{n,t} \in \{0,1\}$ that indicates whether employee $n$ works at day $t$ or not. Let $T$ the total number of days.

We can solve this problem with linear constraints as follows. Introduce an additional binary variable $z_{n,t} \in \{0,1\}$ that indicates whether employee $n$ start a sequence of consecutive working days at day $t$. A sequence of working days starts at day $t$ if the employee does work at day $t$ whilst not working at day $t-1$, i.e., $y_{n,t} = 1$ and $y_{n,t-1} = 0$. Then we can introduce the constraint that a sequence of working days can only start if the following $k-1$ days are also working days.

$$
\begin{align}
  &z_{n,1} = y_{n,1} \>\> \text{for } && && \mbox{First working day}\\
  &z_{n,t} \geq y_{n,t} - y_{n,t-1} &&\text{for } t = 2, \ldots, T && \mbox{First working day}\\
  &k \cdot z_{n,t} \leq \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} y_{n,t+i}    \>\> &&\text{for } t = 1, \ldots, T-k+1 && \mbox{At least $k$ consecutive working days}
\end{align}
$$
The first constraint enforces $z_{n,t}$ to be 1 if employee $n$ starts working at day $t$ and the second constraint enforces $z_{n,t}$ to be zero if employee does not work at least the upcoming $k$ days (including the current day).

Comment: Thank you very much Michiel for the great answer.

Comment: @meteorenthusiast you're welcome! Glad you still have seen the answer and find it useful. If you think this answer solves your problem then there is the option to accept the answer :)

Comment: I have a curiosity, what if we want to have an objective function that gives a better score the more days in a row are reached? For instance, the objective function assign 3 if there are 3 days in a row, 4 if there are 4 days in a row, etc.. Using your approach, should we have a variable z (n,t,k) that is true if the employee n starts k days in a row in the day t? And then in the objective function:  z(n,t,k) * k, to assign a bigger value when k is bigger?

Comment: Ps just accepted the answer, it's very helpful and you kept it linear!

Comment: @meteorenthusiast I'll think about it. Not so much time now.

Comment: great, meanwhile thank you again